# How to dynamically set ViewEncapsulation for a Web Component?

Tags: angular, web-component

I am trying to initialise a component with or without Shadow DOM based on the browser (because IE does not support Shadow DOM).

I check whether it is IE11 and set the encapsulation to `Emulated` for IE and `ShadowDom` for other browsers.

```js
const agent = window.navigator.userAgent;
const isIe11 = agent.indexOf('MSIE') === -1 && agent.indexOf('Trident') > 0;

@Component({
   selector: 'my-web-component',
   templateUrl: '...html',
   styleUrls: ['...scss'],
   encapsulation: isIe11 ? ViewEncapsulation.Emulated : ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit { ... }
```

The value of `isIe11` is correct as per the return value of browser check but the encapsulation always ends up being `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.

I confirmed this via the DOM inspector because I do not see `#shadow-root` in the DOM. Instead, I see `_ngcontent-c0` which confirms the encapsulation is emulated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in the way you envision it, because angular compiles your code in AOT mode, and during the compilation step the browser is obviously not known.

I can only think of one way to achieve this. You have to compile the same application twice. Once for non `ShadowDom` compatible browser, and one in which this is possible.

Then on your server you serve whichever is needed based on the browser requesting it. I suppose you can also find a hacky way to do it inside the `index.html` which will load the correct angular libraries based on the current browser. This will require some after `ng build` script.

You can handle the encapsulation needed from within your environment file though, so if you have two different environments for compatible and non compatible browsers, you can add a property inside your environment:

```
// non shadow dom compatible env
export const environment = {
  // ...
  defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
}


// shadow dom compatible env
export const environment = {
  // ...
  defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
}
```

If you have those two environment files for your production builds, you can edit the `bootstrapModule` method inside your `main.ts` to read the value:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  defaultEncapsulation: environment.defaultEncapsulation
});
```